# Why is my washing machine making this sound?

Tags: appliances, washing-machine

I have uploaded a [short video](http://youtu.be/n-vVNQaHsyg) of my washing machine's spin cycle.  It sounds like there is something scraping and the drum isn't moving very fast.  Any ideas as to what this could be?  Would it be worth my time to take the thing apart?

Comment: Does it happen only on the delicate spin cycle, or on any spin cycle?

Comment: What's the make and model of the machine?

Comment: It happens on all the spin cycles.  Just at different speeds.

Answer (score 1):

Likely a failed transmission (I was going to go with bearing before I heard the video) and likely costs more to fix than getting a new washer (almost certainly costs more to fix than getting a clean, working used washer.) But, if you like to look, look up the "tricks" to getting into your model of washer (the last one I tore down had "places you shoved a putty-knife" that unlatched the cover) - there's usually something non-obvious like that, but the internet has largely circumvented these "trade secrets of the appliance repair trade" if you look hard enough.

It's also helpful to look for **"common problems"** or just **problems** and your model number.